# ASP.Net MVC 2 - Model Coupling with Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, interface, model, entity

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535662/asp-net-mvc-linq-to-sql-data-annotation-validation) question, let's say we have the following scenario -

A model class User that implements `IUser`

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IUser))]
public class User : IUser
```

And a repository that handles saving, retrieving etc. of this from whichever datastore we want to use

```
public class UserRepository : IRepository<User>
IQueryable<User> GetAUserBySomeCriteriaOrOther(int aParam, string anotherParam);
```

Further on we would have a controller and perhaps a view on top as well, each expecting an instance of `IQueryable<User>`.

My questions is thus:
What are the advantages/disadvantages of passing the results back from the repository as (say) an `IQueryable<User>` compared to an `IQueryable<IUser>` ?

My reason for asking is that most examples/demos I see would use `IQueryable<User>`, but this seems to me to be introducing a coupling between higher layers and whichever method I use to generate the `User` class. Say I want to change from Linq-to-Sql to Entity Framework - is that not then a big headache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityFramework does not support querying over interfaces.  Linq2Sql can figure it out ok.

Generally your User class will look the same between all .NET ORMs.  Your linq and model classes will probably not change when you switch ORMS.

Comment: Sorry to labour the point a bit but to be clear:

In the example, I would have a class User, which would be passed back from whatever repository/ORM I used?

So I could start with Linq2SQL, get a month down the line, and decide actually let's change to NHibernate and so long as the NHibernate repository returned the same User class, the layers above would carry on happily?

Comment: Most likely.  The shape/definition of your User wouldn't change and therefore all calling code wouldn't care.  I have a demo/scratchpad project I constantly switch ORMs for and its pretty easy to do.