# how to validate in Linq to Sql using Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

i m using Linq to SQl for my project, i tried all CRUD operations (Create, Delete, Edit, details) its working, but how to perform validation, means adding Required , Range, and other common Validation using System. Data. Annotation class,

I don know how to do this, please help me in detail, as i am beginner, how should i validate all user input fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC, Linq to SQL Data Annotation Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535662/asp-net-mvc-linq-to-sql-data-annotation-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a partial class for the entity and add a [MetadataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) on it.
Then create the meta data class with object properties and then put annotations on them.

http://diegworld.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-dataannotations-to-validate.html

Comment: i tried, that but i'm confused what to create as partial claass , how it should be named ? please can u explain in detail, i have a dataclasses1.dbml (linq to Sql file ), now how u add this metadata attirbute, please really waiting for help :(

Comment: thank you. i got the solution by referening  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535662/asp-net-mvc-linq-to-sql-data-annotation-validation